# Django Admin Crash When Default Storage Changed

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-admin, django-storage

I'm trying to change the default storage of a model in django so that it stores files in an amazon S3 bucket

the bucket has the next permissions:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1680906499830",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1680906498320",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tuenlaceinmobiliariodevelopmentbucket/*"
    }
]
```

}

This project is based on django cookiecutter, https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django in docker container

I need to be able to load images from django admin,
but the page loads only in html, the admin tried to load static files from the bucket and I don't know how to make it work correctly, I can still navigate to the create images form, however when I fill out the file form and press the button save, the manager throws an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONS error. Even so, the image is stored in the Amazon S3 bucket, but django admin stops working.

This is my configuration

```
#model
class Image(Item,models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='images/'
)   

#admin
@admin.register(Image)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = (
    'nombre',
    'descripcion',
    'image'
)

search_fields = (
    'nombre',
    'descripcion',
    'image'
)

#compose_file
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
COLLECTFAST_STRATEGY = "collectfast.strategies.boto3.Boto3Strategy"
```